# How do I evaluate bool in a IF statement between a positive and negative integer in C++?

Tags: c++

I am trying compare a variable in my program against a negative number in my Arduino project. Scratch code is as follows -

```
int y = 40;

if (y < -100){
    do something;
}
```

However when I try to verify my code in Arduino IDE I am greeted with this error message,

```
sketch_apr23a.ino: In function 'void loop()':
sketch_apr23a:32: error: 'l00' was not declared in this scope
```

I am assuming it's because the - negative sign infront of 100 is being interperted as some sort of operator perhaps?

What is the best way to compare an integer against a negative integer in an if statement in C++?

Thank you!!!!!!

EDIT - I can't believe I typed an L in there, sorry to waste your time with something so noobish! I really appreciate your help though, and my code verified just fine after the fix, thanks so much everyone! I will accept the first answer submitted once my 12 minutes is up!

Comment: You've typed a small letter `l` instead of a `1`. So it thinks it's a variable that hasn't been declared.

Comment: It says "l00" .. not 1 but l

Comment: ... really? Oh dear. One sec ;) How embarassing. Too many drinks...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're confused with `l00` and `100`.

Answer (score 3):

it should be `100`(one zero zero) not `l00` (L zero zero)